# How do I incrementally merge an object variable in Terraform, with multiple tfvars files

Tags: terraform

So I have a setup where I need to be able to build out multiple clusters in multiple locations using basically the same set of terraform variables with subtle changes.

I have multiple tfvar and provider files, to define just a little bit more of the variables each time, until everything is set.

So I have a single, base, common tfvars file, then location tfvar files, then instance tfvar files, where every ultimate cluster will include the common file, then the location file then the instance file.

However, for some stuff, I define the variable as an object map, so I can store things in a complex form, for example:-

```
cluster_secrets = {
  "argocd-cluster-secret" = {
    namespace = "argocd",
    cluster_name = "...",
    cluster_server = "https://rancher.....io/k8s/clusters/c-nnnnn",
    cluster_bearertoken = "token-..."
  }
}
```

So the question is, can I just override the cluster_name, in the location.tfvars file, the cluster_server, in an instance.tfvars file, and everything else in the common.tfvars file?  I think I may need to convert this to a list (multiple cluster_secrets), which would make separate variables, problematic.

I know I can break it all out to separate variables (if there is only one cluster_secret), but that will make the whole thing messy, so I'd like to avoid that.

Any suggestions?

Edit: Providing a semi-example, in response to Marcin's question

So to illustrate the problem, I think it might help to explain how my `backend "s3"` was, and now is, defined, as it illustrates the point.  My original `backend "s3"`, for the 'a' cluster in our 'eu-west-4' location was this:-

```
backend "s3" {
  bucket                      = "<eu-west-4-location>-a"
  key                         = "tfstate.tf"
  region                      = "eu-west-4"
  endpoint                    = "http://<eu-west-4-api-ip>:8080"
  iam_endpoint                = "http://<eu-west-4-api-ip>:8080"
  sts_endpoint                = "http://<eu-west-4-api-ip>:8080"
  encrypt                     = false
  force_path_style            = true
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_region_validation      = true
}
```

But to have multiple redefinitions of that, for each of the 'a' and 'b' clusters in each of the 6 different locations, is messy.  So ultimately I split it out to a 'common' provider.tf, which includes just:-

```
backend "s3" {
  key                         = "tfstate.tf"
  encrypt                     = false
  force_path_style            = true
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_region_validation      = true
}
```

a backend for each location (the eu-west-4 location called .tf.backend which includes):-

```
backend "s3" {
  region                      = "eu-west-4"
  endpoint                    = "http://<eu-west-4-api-ip>:8080"
  iam_endpoint                = "http://<eu-west-4-api-ip>:8080"
  sts_endpoint                = "http://<eu-west-4-api-ip>:8080"
}
```

and the cluster instance, for the 'a' cluster ("-a.tf.backend") includes just:-

```
backend "s3" {
  bucket                      = "<eu-west-4-location>-a"
}
```

My script for running terraform is thus:-
`terraform init -reconfigure -backend-config=${CLUSTER_LOCATION}.tf.backend -backend-config=${CLUSTER_INSTANCE}.tf.backend`

Hence I pull together all 3 files, for each cluster, regardless of the instance name, or the location, and I get the original backend assembled each time.

However, as I understand it with variables, if you attempt something similar, you'd end up with just the later, cluster_instance, definition of the variable, as the whole object would be redefined, rather than adding properties.

Hence my question, any idea how to handle variables, in the same way that it handles backend objects?

Comment: Do you have any complete example of those vars the you are referring to, and what "incrementally overwrite" means in your setup?

Comment: Deleted my earlier comment, as I added an Edit, which largely replaced it (hopefully answering Marcin's question better).